# Javascript for of loop to append with JQuery only appends to first element

Tags: javascript, jquery

For whatever reason, this only appends to the `#category` element

```
    var categoriesListOptions = []
    for(i of categories){
        var option = document.createElement('option')
        option.innerHTML = i
        option.value = i
        categoriesListOptions.push(option)
    }

    $('#category').empty()
    $('#show').empty()

    for(i of categoriesListOptions){
        $('#category').append(i)
        $('#show').append(i)
    }
```

I know for sure this isn't a problem with the id names, because if switched around `#category` and `#show`, it would only append it for the first one.

```
    for(i of categoriesListOptions){
        $('#show').append(i) // << only works for this one
        $('#category').append(i)
    }
```

Iv'e logged `categoriesListOptions` to the console, and couldn't find a problem. I even did a `console.log(i)` in the start and end of the `for(i of categoriesListOptions) loop`, and came out perfectly.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried to change the order of `category` and `show`? try to append to `show` first.

Comment: You are appending the same dom object to two different elements. Appending moves the element from its previous location in the dom hierarchy to the new one. So you are putting it in `category` but then immediately moving it to `show`. If you wanted two similar elements you need to clone them, and then append the original to one parent and append the clone to the other

Comment: @Prime Yep, just updated the question to make that clear.

Comment: thanks @PatrickEvans, this worked: const a = i.cloneNode(true)

Comment: @bmn1 You need to understand what referense is all about, when you add i to category first and then you add i to show, it will move i from category to show. thats why you need to clone i and then add it to show